# Was bedeutet "nun" in diesem Satz?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adverb, tense, modal-particle

Guten Tag,

ich verstehe nicht, warum "nun" im folgenden Satz verwendet wurde.

> "Neuere Ergebnisse haben nun ergeben, dass Handysucht körperliche Symptome hat."

Das Verb bezieht sich auf die Vergangenheit, während "nun" eine gegenwärtige Bedeutung hat. Könnte es auf das, was in Englisch "Present Perfect" genannt wird, hinweisen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Zum Tempus **Perfekt**

Es scheint mir ein Missverständnis zu sein, dass das Tempus 'Perfekt' immer eine rein in der Vergangenheit liegende Handlung oder einen in der Vergangenheit liegenden Prozess bezeichnet. Zumindest wird das Perfekt oft herangezogen, um vorrangig das gegenwärtige Ergebnis eines vergangenen Vorgangs zu bezeichnen:

> Sie hat letztes Jahr geheiratet.

heißt **auch**: *Sie ist seit einem Jahr verheiratet = nicht mehr 'zu haben'.* Ob eher die vergangene oder die aktuelle Bedeutung akzentuiert ist, hängt vom Kontext und vom Verb ab:

> Sie hat letztes Jahr mit großem Tamtam geheiratet, es waren 200 Hochzeitsgäste da. > *Ereignis der Vergangenheit*
>
> Wenn sie arbeitet, hat sie das Telefon immer abgestellt. > *generelle Aussage mit Präsens als 'Generalzeit' = das ist immer so, auch jetzt*

Oft vermischen sich die beiden Bedeutungen:

> Sie hat ihr Hochzeitsbild zerrissen = 1. *sie hat es getan* und 2. *sie will es nicht mehr sehen*.

Es dürfte vergleichsweise wenige Verben geben, die ein 'präsentisches Perfekt' erlauben. Manche verfügen darüber als spezielle Gebrauchsweise: *Die Bank hat noch geöffnet.*

Das Präteritum Passiv verhält sich ähnlich: Wenn ein Straßenabschnitt fertiggestellt und freigegeben wurde, dann kann er jetzt befahren werden.

In der Phrase '*Untersuchungen haben ergeben, dass*' ist auch der folgende Nebensinn beteiligt: '*es gibt inzwischen (mehr oder weniger solide gewonnene) Aussagen dazu, dass*' bzw. '*es gibt Ergebnisse aus Untersuchungen, die besagen, dass*'. Eine eindeutig vergangenheitsbezogene Aussage wäre '*In den letzten Jahren wurden dazu viele Untersuchungen durchgeführt*'.

2. Bedeutung von **nun**

Das Adverb *nun* hat neben der temporalen Bedeutung *'jetzt'* auch eine satz-adverbielle oder partikelähnliche Bedeutung in Richtung von '*allerdings*' bzw. '*jetzt aber*'. Sie tritt auch als '*nun aber*' auf und kommt in Gedankenfiguren wie 'einerseits - andererseits' bzw. 'bis jetzt - jetzt aber' bzw. überhaupt als Markierung der zeitlichen Aufeinanderfolge vor:

> Bis jetzt war man immer davon ausgegangen, dass der Mensch sich als Wirtschaftssubjekt rational verhält. Nun aber stellt sich heraus, dass viele Handlungen der Wirtschaftsteilnehmer sich nicht rein rational erklären lassen.

Ich vermute, dass diese kontrastive Bedeutung von *nun aber* im Ausgangsbeispiel von Bornak assoziiert ist. Mit Sicherheit ist anzunehmen, dass der Satz auf einen Vorgängersatz verweist, der ungefähr folgendermaßen gelautet haben könnte:

> Bisher dachte man, dass Handysucht vor allem im mentalen und psychischen Bereich schädlich wirkt.

oder

> Körperliche Entzugserscheinungen bei Handysucht hielt man bislang für unmöglich.

Answer (score 2):

Jein, im Deutschen kann man *jetzt* und *nun* mit Präsens Perfekt kombinieren für das was auf Englisch Present Perfect ist, aber dies ist in deinem Satz hier nicht unbedingt der Fall, da nicht genug Kontext angegeben. Es gibt 2 mögliche Interpretationen:

- dass das "nun" hier [partikelhaft](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nun_aber_etwa_eben) verwendet wurde, a-la "*Die Arznei galt lange als harmlos. Inzwischen haben neuere Ergebnisse nun das Gegenteil ergeben*".
- die von dir erwartete zeitliche Intepretation ist auch möglich, siehe [Bedeutung 3](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nun_inzwischen_jetzt_heute).

Wie üblich, sind Wörterbücher wie Duden deine Freunde.